# Tracing (set -x) in a subshell

Tags: bash, set

The builtin expression `set -x` turns on tracing, which prints each command after globbing but before execution. What I'm curious about is the difference of output `set -x` provides in different contexts.

When I run `bash -c 'set -x; echo "hello"'` we see...

```
+ echo hello
hello
```

When I run `bash -c '(set -x; echo "hello")'` we see...

```
+ echo hello
hello
```

When I run `bash -c 'hi=$(set -x; echo "hello")'` we see...

```
++ echo hello
```

Does anyone know why there is a double `+` in the last case?

Comment: Not that it helps with this question but as an FYI you can do: `bash -xc 'echo hello'`

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) for `set -x`:

> Print a trace of simple commands, `for` commands, `case` commands, `select` commands, and arithmetic `for` commands and their arguments or associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are executed. The value of the `PS4` variable is expanded and the resultant value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

`PS4` is [described as](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PS4):

> The value of this parameter is expanded like *PS1* and the expanded value is the prompt printed before the command line is echoed when the `-x` option is set (see [The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)). The first character of the expanded value is replicated multiple times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indirection. The default is ‘`+`’.

The repeated `+` symbols indicate the levels of indirection:

- `set -x; echo "hello"` runs with a single level;
- `hi=$(set -x; echo "hello")` runs with two: the subshell environment used for the substitution is a second level.

The levels of indirection aren’t counted from the level at which the `set -x` command is run; they are counted from the “main” shell.

This character replication is unique to Bash; other shells don’t indicate the shell depth in this way.

Comment: I thought `bash -c '(set -x; echo "hello")' ` would also create a subshell, and yet it only outputs a single `+`. Why is this?